# Why is my neural network training slowing down over time?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a simple neural network on word embeddings. I'm trying to save a plot of the embeddings every 1000 epochs:

```
if epo%1000 == 0:
    print(f'Epoch {epo}')

    #save plots
    W = net.fc1.weight
    W = W.detach().numpy()

    svd = decomposition.TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
    W1_dec = svd.fit_transform(W.T)
    x = W1_dec[:,0]
    y = W1_dec[:,1]
    plot = sns.scatterplot(x, y)

    for i in range(0,W1_dec.shape[0]):
        plot.text(x[i], y[i]+2e-2, list(vocabulary.keys())[i], horizontalalignment='center', size='small', color='black', weight='semibold')
    plt.savefig(f'images/epoch{epo}.png')
```

The training and the plots will be great initially, but after a while they will slow down considerably. I've seen this issue before when the entire computational graph was used every time, but I don't see where I could do the same over here.

I tried removing the plotting part (under "#save plots") and everything works just fine and doesn't slow down.

**Update**

Looks like the last line is the one that is slowing the process down:
`plt.savefig(f'images/epoch{epo}.png')`

Not sure how to fix it

Comment: have you tried placing the plot part in a separate function? It is hard to know from your examples what the dimensions are. Maybe dimensions grow & there is a lot more to save as the time passes by.

Comment: I haven't. The dimensions stay the same though. They are (100,2) -- 100 points, `x,y` for each

Comment: Another thing that I don't know if you have tried. Have you tried to keep one single plot object and clear it before making a new one?

Comment: I haven't but I actually just saw it somewhere else. Trying to figure out how to do that. Any suggestions on how to do that?